# Can't populate properties of the object with PDO::FETCH_CLASS

Tags: php, pdo

How does PDO work in this situation? What I have done wrong? I supposed, that variable $full would have output **"John Smith"**, because the instance of the class is $user in both situations.

I've tried to debug this piece of program, I've put a watcher on $first_name. When degugger enters in the scope of the class I see the output "John".

What I should add/change in this code to get output **"John Smith"**?

```
// user.php file

    class User
    {
        ...
        private $first_name;
        private $last_name;

        public function findById($id = 0)
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table . " WHERE id = :id";
            $params = [":id" => $id];
            $class = get_called_class();
            $result = $this->findBySql($sql, $params);
            return $this->db->fetchObject($result, $class);
        }

        public function findBySql($sql, $params = [])
        {
            return $this->db->query($sql, $params);
        }

        public function fullName()
        {
            return $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;
        }
    }

    // database.php file

    class DataBase
    {     
        ...

        public function fetchObject($stmt, $className = "stdClass")
        {
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $className);
            return $result[0];
        }
    }

    // index.php

    $user = new User();
    $found = $user->findById(1);
    $full = $user->fullName();
    var_dump($full); // output: string ' ' (length=1) -----> supposed: "John Smith"
    var_dump($found); /* output: object(User)[5]
      ....
      private 'first_name' => string 'John' (length=4)
      private 'last_name' => string 'Smith' (length=5)
      ....
    */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Database::fetchObject` is returning a new instance of the class, not modifying the object that called it. Use:

```
public function findById($id = 0)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table . " WHERE id = :id";
    $params = [":id" => $id];
    $class = get_called_class();
    $result = $this->findBySql($sql, $params);
    $user = $this->db->fetchObject($result, $class);
    $this->first_name = $user->first_name;
    $this->last_name = $user->last_name;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: This solution isn't working, but I understood what u've meant!

Comment: This solution works too... I suppose, that all magic is in PDO API, because I can't understand the logic of the code.

Comment: It has very little to do with PDO. The point is that `fetch()` always returns a new object that contains the row from the database. Since you want to modify the current object, you need to copy the values from the returned object into the current object.

Comment: Thank you too for your help. I think in my situation this solution will be better.

Answer (score 0):

`$user` is an empty object, its properties aren't set anywhere.

When you call `$user->findById(1)`, it calls `$db->fetchObject($result, "User");`, which calls `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $className);`, which returns a new User object (actually it's an array containing the object), different from the one you created.

This object has its properties filled, and is returned by all the functions, then stored in the `$found` variable, which is a different variable, and have a different object associated, than the `$user` variable.

You're calling the `fullName()` method on the `$user` variable, which is associated to an empty object, so the return value is a space character (the result of `"" . " " . ""`).

You can change `$user->fullName()` by `$found->fullName()`, and everything should work fine, since `$found` contains the data you loaded from your database.

Comment: You're right! But could u explain a bit more intelligibly what is happening? Can't exactly understand how it's working...

Comment: @Killuminati: I've added more details to help you, but you should really learn more about how OOP works in PHP.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so as I thought from php.net:
"PDO::FETCH_CLASS: Returns instances of the specified class, mapping the columns of each row to named properties in the class".